# openfeint dashbaord doesnt disaplys achivement/leaderboard

Tags: ios, openfeint

I am integrating OpenFeint for the first time. I initialized Openfeint also added achievements in openfeint developer dash board.
But whenever I call launchDashBoard achievement icon is not getting displayed. 
Even 'launchDashboardWithAchievementsPage' does not bring the achievement page.

Help me,
Shakthi